# Modal operator updating an armature is very slow

Tags: armature, operator

I have a modal operator that gets executed only by the 'TIMER' event 30x per second. There is one armature in the scene and nothing else. As soon as I tag the armature for update

```
my_armature.update_tag()
```

and do nothing else, the scene is lagging, dropping down to 10fps. Using the same armature with keyframes and hitting play at 30fps, everything is smooth, even if I import the armature's mesh as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what I did wrong, but I'm pretty sure the issue was on my side of the code. After a major cleanup everything runs smoothly.